# web sockets programming deployed into the tomcat shows error

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

am using windows 7,jdk1.7.0_67,apache-tomcat-7.0.54 for developing web socket program everything is working fine but when i deployed into the server it will show error like this

"JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocket JARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. "

so my web socket is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your error

> *JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6.*

have you checked to see if you've got a Java 6 JRE installed that is being picked up by your Tomcat installation instead of the JRE in your JDK?